# Possible to make C++ shared dynamic library for iOS in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ios-frameworks

As of iOS8, you can use dynamic link libraries (frameworks). Is there any way to make a Cross Platform Shared library in Visual Studio that targets a dynamic library for iOS?

Currently, I only see options for static ".a" in the iOS shared library project properties.

Even if I have to work around this by compiling manually on the Mac, in XCode or command line, I'm curious to know if there's a way to do this by starting with a shared library in Visual Studio 2015?

The context for this is that we're porting over some C++ DLL's to work on iOS (and maybe Android too). It seems our options now are to make shared C++ libraries or port the C++ DLL's to C# and use Xamarin (probably a little bit more work porting wise)

I am open to someone making a case about "why we should stick with static libraries in the iOS world, and here's what your general app architecture should be"

Coming from a Win32 and COM background, have a little experience with *NIX systems, but not OSX/iOS... so there's a good chance that I'm not up to par on general architecture for that platform.

**Succinctly, here's the question I'm asking:**

Can I build dynamic linked libraries for iOS using Visual Studio 2015, or am I confined to using static libraries?

Comment: I think you are mixing too many things together. VS is IDE, so you can write the source C++ in it for sure. Then you can use MS CC to compile MSWin .dll (or static lib) from it, but MS CC does not support iOS platform... actually now I recall the MS CC already supports ARM CPUs for Windows Phone, so maybe it can be bent even to compile working binary for iOS, but to have fully supported build tool-chain you will have to stick with XCode (it's compiler) for binary building. For android the situation is same, I would suggest to use Android NDK (which is currently wrapping GCC+CLANG compilers).

Comment: I'm actually supporting at work something like that, having single C++ source, developed in linux (compiled + tested with GCC and CLANG), then I cross compile it for android at the same machine with NDK, then our iOS and WP guys fetch the source, and build it with XCode/VS. Each platform has to have it's own project configuration, a bit hassle, but workable. Whether the iOS does use .a or .so is of no interest to me, that's their own decision and affects their integration into the mobile app, not affecting my core lib C++ source in any way.

Comment: Maybe you want to have the same binary library for all platforms? I don't think the iOS can load windows .dll properly (even if it would contain valid ARM binary). Also IIRC the Apple is using slightly customized ARMs (or better to say "uncommonly configured", than customized), so by compiling specifically for particular iPhone class you can get quite some performance boost by using all the extended ARM instructions available on that CPU. That's the reason why I didn't even try to use Android ARM binary on iOS, even if there would be some compatible .so file format.

Comment: VS2015 has the capability to connect to a Mac running some host software, ship the source code over and compile the code on the Mac and target specific platforms. VS initiates the compilation, I'm just wondering if there's some kind of a backdoor to control the commands that VS uses to compile, e.g. maybe I can provide arguments to make it compile to an ARM binary that's dynamically linked, etc. I think Microsoft would love to have a unified build/test/debug environment for iOS for C++ and C#. They're basically there with C# using Xamarin, but C++ has a little ways to go.

Comment: I'm not sure.. sounds to me like distributed compilation, that's unrelated to platform support. If MSCC is capable to cross compile, you can compile for ARM on your Win PC too. You have to check 1) if MSCC can build proper ARM variants (both 32b and 64b) 2) if it can save object files/shared libs in formats compatible with iOS or XCode. If not, there's very likely some way how to call XCode build externally trough some custom build step script, but this is completely beyond my expertise. I personally prefer GNUmake+bash for everything (calling native build tools).